# How to Fix "A disk Read error occurred" after installing windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, bios, uefi, windows-installation

I have two HDD in pc,I had windows 10 installed on sperate HDD and get to install windows 7 on completely different partition ,but after installation when i turn on pc a message pop saying disk read error and restart doesn't work .

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, Boot OS from Hard Drive

If no help, enter WinRE to repair Master Boot Record and Boot Sector

bootrec /rebuildbcd

bootrec /fixmbr

bootrec /fixboot

Comment: When i try to enter repair it goes to windows 10 manager it is weird